# How to set focus using jQuery on an element that has just appeared

Tags: jquery, focus, show, setfocus

I have a document ready block as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addTagLink').click(function () {
        $('#addTagField').show();
        $('#addTagField').val("");
        $('#addTagField').focus();
    });
});
```

The `addTagField` is a regular text input that has display:none set by css on page load.

When a user clicks on the `addTagLink`  element the input field is shown correctly but focus doesn't get set to the field as intended.

I figured it must be something to do with the display:none / show() functionality, so changed the `$('#addTagField').focus();` to another field `$('#name').focus();`which worked perfectly.

Can anyone suggest firstly why I see this issue and secondly, how to fix it?

Comment: It works just fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KN6rs/) - click the show text to show the input and set focus to it.

Comment: Thanks Christofer - I found the issue, a mistake in wrong ids! :/

Comment: you can try this $('input:text:first').focus();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with my element IDs. Oops.

Answer (score 10):

```
// Variable to store element
var btn = document.querySelector( ".btn-primary");

// Click Event
$(btn).click(function() {

  // Jquery to define which element will get focus
  $(".form-control").focus();

});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the code for reference.